# Replacing Meta Viewport tag in HTML emails with alternative CSS solution

Tags: css, windows-phone-7, html-email, meta, email-templates

We removed the meta viewport tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0" />` from our HTML emails to increase support for legacy Blackberrys. It's documented to potentially cause blank screens at least according to blogs on major email testing services.

The only downside we've seen in testing is it shrinks the results on Windows Phone HTC HD7.  (https://litmus.com/pub/71916b3) In Litmus tests including the tag shows the page at 100% zoom. When it's removed it shows the email zoomed out fit to screen. This occurs even when there are no problems with other mobile platforms.

Is there another CSS technique that could replace the tag and get around this?

The tag is included used in one of the more prominent [HTML email boilerplate templates.](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/) In practice, we've only seen problems with `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` causing blank BB screens.

We've tried targeting the issue media queries and zoom, but there is too much of a risk of them affecting other phones with similar sizes and pixel densities. Probably another tradeoff, typical of email, but wanted to post because I haven't seen much on this.

Comment: Originally included it only because we saw it in boilerplates, but outside of the Windows Phone issue we see no differences. Seems outmoded. Think it helped to correct sizing re: pixel density issues -- but there's another meta tag just for that.

Comment: What is the goal of including the `viewport` meta tag?

Comment: With the Viewport tag Windows Phone 7.5 in Litmus tests shows the page at 100% zoom. When it's removed it show the email zoom out fit to screen. Even when there are no problems with other mobile platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The W3C is supporting [a CSS solution](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#the-atviewport-rule) anyway, though it’ll be a while until it’s full supported. Microsoft seems to [be on board with it](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/windows-8-surface-ie10-html5), however, so you can try that.

The prefix-free syntax is `@viewport`, and Microsoft uses `@-ms-viewport`.

Comment: Thank you. I tested this and had no luck with Windows Phone 7.5. The solution I mentioned below seems to work, but for Windows Phone 8 this is great. Unless you've tried this with 7.5? Anyway appreciate the sources and worth the bounty.

Comment: Thank you. I haven’t tried it with 7.5, no, I just read about that recently, and though it’d be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I may have come across a solution in testing. I'm not positive that this doesn't cause some other tradeoff and would still be happy to select and award the bounty if there's an answer with a better approach.

I'm seeing no issue with Blackberry's and Windows Phone 7.5 renders at 100%

```
<!--[if IE]> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<![endif]-->
```